# Iterate each row om table and make api call

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'm trying to iterate through each and every row in my table and using the book and author value, i make an api call and get some details and populate my string. 
The problem I have here is that when I hit submit, my str_tot is empty. When I added alert statements to figure out why this was happening, .each function seems to take all the values from the table at once and then enter the api call loop with just the last value.

There is a 1 sec delay for the api call to make the call and get the info. This is a little strange and ive exhausted my options trying to identify the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<table id="list">
<thead>
 <th>Author</th>
 <th>Book</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="check"><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
<td class="author">Name1</td>
<td class="book">Book1</td>
</tr>
...
...
...
<tr>
<td class="author">Name10</td>
<td class="book">Book10</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var str_tot = " ";
$('#submit').click(function () {
$('#list > tbody > tr').each(function () { 

             var author = $(this).find('td.author').val();
             var book = $(this).find('td.book').val();

             if($(this).find('td.check').find("input").is(':checked')) {

                 var url = "http://api.book.com/some/link/search?query="+author+"&title[]=booktitle:"+book;
                 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                    var book = data.result[0]["book"];
                    var author = data.result[0]["author"];
                 });
                str_tot = str_tot + " " + author + " " + book; 
           });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX called the service asynchronously, so after calling `$.getJSON` method, it will immediately step to next instruction i.e

`str_tot = str_tot + " " + author + " " + book;`

So move the above statement inside callback function.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     var book = data.result[0]["book"];
     var author = data.result[0]["author"];

      str_tot = str_tot + " " + author + " " + book; 
});
```

Comment: Im sorry for the misleading code. It is exactly as you pointed out. I cannot post the code here, so had to rewrite it and made a mistake while I did it.